# How to copy content of an opened notepad instance?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I need to get the text found in an notepad process instance that isn't saved on the hard-drive. For example the notepad app is opened and contains a string "This is a notepad Window" but still isn't saved, I wanna get the string inside the notepad without saving it to a file.
I must complete this task, in powershell. But if it can't be done in powershell C# is the next best option. The closest thing to my case I found in an answer on stack overflow is the following code in C#, but I couldn't really figure out how to make use of it

I've tried dumping the memory data of the notepad app, but it wasn't useful.
I've tried creating an com object for the notepad app but it wasn't doable.
Code I talked about:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

private void btnCopyToNotepad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartNotepad();

    Process[] notepads = null;
    while (notepads == null || notepads.Length == 0)
    {
        notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");   
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    if (notepads.Length == 0) return;
    if (notepads[0] != null)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
        SendMessage(FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null), 0x000C, 0, textBox1.Text);
    }
}
private static void StartNotepad() 
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
}
```

I expect to be able to copy the text from a running notepad instance without saving it on the hard-drive.

Comment: Sory, of my question, but why do you need to do that ? One french humorist said "Tell us what you need, we’ll tell you how to do without it" ;o)

Comment: @JPBlanc , it's a part of a project am working on to keep track of employee work and add their progress to a database in case of sudden system shutdown, so their work wouldn't be lost; and they mostly use text editors like notepad.. I know it may seem silly but for it's really beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for...

> I expect to be able to copy the text from a running notepad instance
>   without saving it on the hard-drive.

...why are you trying to grab something that you had to put there to start with?

Or... are you saying, some other process started and wrote something to notepad?

If so, then capture why not just content from the other process before it goes to notepad?

Anyway, you can just do something like this directly and avoid all the C# stuff...

Old school...

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.AppActivate((Get-Process -Name notepad).MainWindowTitle) 
$wshell.SendKeys("^{A}^{C}")
```

Or via .Net

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic") 
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate((Get-Process -Name notepad).MainWindowTitle) 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{A}^{C}")
```

***Update for OP***

As for …

> Any Chance we can get the text from the memory ? Without using the
>   Send Keys ?

Not without using some other 3rd UI Automation tool, or writing your own or memory dumping (but the last one is a serialization thing, soooo..., it would be just as easy to save the notepad session in a tempo location and call it up later).

There 3rdP tools around for PowerShell UI automation. Be aware some are no longer updated, though they still work.

Still, you'd have to get these on every system you need to hit.

Here is a list:

[WASP](https://eddytechdotnet.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/using-wasp-and-powershell-for-powerful-windows-gui-automation/)
[UiAutomation](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=uiautomation)
[selenium](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) 
[FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI)
[BitCollectors.UIAutomationLib](https://github.com/aplocher/BitCollectors.UIAutomationLib) 
[AutoIt Scripting Language](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit)
https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell

Otherwise, you end up digging at this.

[Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/inspect-objects)
[UI Automation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)

As per the author, with FlaUI, you would do something like this.

```
Add-Type -Path "\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\FlaUI\src\FlaUI.UIA3\bin\Debug\FlaUI.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\FlaUI\src\FlaUI.UIA3\bin\Debug\FlaUI.UIA3.dll"

$app = [FlaUI.Core.Application]::AttachOrLaunch('notepad')

$uia = New-Object FlaUI.UIA3.UIA3Automation

$mw = $app.GetMainWindow($uia)

$Document = $mw.FindFirstChild($uia.ConditionFactory.ByControlType([FlaUI.Core.Definitions.ControlType]::Document))

$mw.Title
$Document.Patterns.Value.Pattern.Value.Value
```

Sure, SendKeys can be finicky (but easy to use), and the list are more polished, but use similar approaches.

Comment: Any Chance we can get the text from the memory ? Without using the Send Keys ?

Comment: See my update for you. As you will note, there are other options, and I've tried them all, and keep them around as I see this sort of question more often that I'd normally expect.

Comment: I really Appreciate your help it was very useful thank you very much. Am new to stack overflow, it's good to know that there are professionals ready to help. Thank you again.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to retrieve this from memory. By using Spy++ (which comes with Visual Studio) you can actually see the text in an open notepad window (I haven't been able to reverse-engineer which WIN32API is called for this, it's not GetWindowText on the child window).

Comment: Henry, no worries. bluuf, Yeppers on Spy++, and your observation is why I did not include it, as I was never able to figure that one out either, besides with all the other available tools, I took that stance that it was just way too much unnecessary work. Well, that and still required getting Spy++ on every target, just like the others. You can get Spy++ without having Visual Studio. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx